# Checking entry in the log file using RegEx in unit testing

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I have log4net log file that logs entries for certain errors. I have to check after i.e. 30 seconds the first error it logged in the log file. I believe Reg Ex is what can do it. 
So far I have:

```
string dataToLog = "certain logged error message";
var matches = Regex.Matches(File.ReadAllText(logfile), dataToLog);
Assert.AreEqual(3, matches.Count);
```

Above code works fine for number of errors in whole file. But I need to 
add to it code which can check and return Boolean  i.e after 20 seconds first error it logged or not. Any idea how to accomplish that?

Comment: Is your problem "reading the log file after 30 seconds" or "understanding what is in the file"?

Comment: Yes problem is reading the log file after 30 seconds.

Comment: Do you know how to use timers? See for example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx

Comment: Shouldn't it be 30 in the second last line as well? i.e after 30 seconds first error it logged

Comment: Just a small remark: since unit tests are supposed to be fast I would use the term integration test.

Comment: Yes after 30 seconds first error logged. But file itself covers hours in between I choose between this and that range.

Comment: Can you show a line from the error log. It seems you are unsure how to do several things: "after thirty seconds", "read the first line", "extract the time stamp". If I am right, then please edit your question to make that very clear - and include the first few lines of the error log file. Then you will get a good answer quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following code before reading the log file :

```
DateTime dt30 = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30);
            while(DateTime.Now!=dt30)
            {
                continue;
            }
```

Comment: What I have to do is read the first time stamp in the log file than add 30 seconds. How do you read the first time stamp in a log file?

Comment: Can you put a sample of your log file.

Answer (score 0):

You can just freeze current thread for period given:

```
Start();
Thread.Sleep("30000"); // 30 sec
Read();
```

or support a callback or event.